# Theorem prover for C#

Tags: java, c#

I have already read some older articles here in the forum on theorem proofers, but the articles are quite old, so I would like to open a new question for here.

So I have the following case: we have a Java project that uses a theorem prover library. In this case, for example, certain expressions are checked for satisfiability. This is an important thing in machine learning. Our problem now is that we have to convert this program into a C# version (thats an option, translate). The C# environment includes several algorithms. This programmed in Java should now be integrated into the C# environment We stand here something on the hose, since it does not give the logic library unfortunately for C#.

In general, I have not found enough in the search for logic libraries or theorem proofers, some articles are very old, so I do not know if that would be so practicable today.

My question is divided into two, for one, which logic libraries or theorem provers are there for C#? Is anyone here experiences? Second, how would you proceed with the described problem of the conversion of Java into C#?

I hope my comments are understandable. I would be very happy about lots of feedback / feedback / tips!

Comment: [Tangible has all kinds of translators](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/converters.html). However, I was not very happy with the quality 5 years ago.

Comment: I think: hire a developer who is experienced in both languages and let him translate the code. There are subtle differences between Java and C# which are not so simple to spot. It starts with the `byte` datatype which is -128 to +127 in Java but 0 to 255 in C#. Very annoying if you don't know it.